# ES6 map is throwing error on array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
const normalizeEventTypes = nextProps.events.space_events.map(obj, i => 
     obj.id
)
```

I code obj is not defined, my array of object look like this

```
{
    "space_events": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Anniversaries"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Brand Rollout"
        }
    }]
}
```

am I missing something?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Note @MayankShukla below. Make sure to accept it, if the problem is indeed resolved.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to use `()`, write it like this:

```
const normalizeEventTypes = nextProps.events.space_events.map((obj, i) => 
     obj.id
)
```

**Reason**:

You are using obj and index both parameters in `map` callback function so you need to use `()` to wrap the parameters, like this:

```
a = b.map((i,j) => i)
```

These `()` are optional when we want to use only one parameter, like this:

```
a = b.map(i => i)
```

**Different ways of using `map`:**

**1.** `a.map(i => i + 1); //when index is not required`

**2.**

```
 a.map(i => {  //when want to do some calculation
       //some calculation
       return //something;
 })
```

**3.** `a.map((i,j) => i + j) //when want to use the index of item`

Check the working snippet:

```js
let data = {
    "space_events": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Anniversaries"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Brand Rollout"
        }
    ]
}

let result = data.space_events.map((obj,i) => obj.name);

console.log('result', result);
```